# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: in KERAS LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, lstm

I have the following lstm model:

```
class LSTM_model():

def __init__(self):
    w2v_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, size=150, window=10, min_count=2, workers=10)
    pretrained_weights = w2v_model.wv.syn0
    vocab_size, emdedding_size = pretrained_weights.shape
    self.w2v_model = w2v_model
    self.keras_lstm_model = Sequential()
    self.keras_lstm_model.add(Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size, output_dim = emdedding_size, weights = [pretrained_weights]))
    self.keras_lstm_model.add(LSTM(units = emdedding_size))
    self.keras_lstm_model.add(Dense(units = vocab_size))
    self.keras_lstm_model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    self.keras_lstm_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['mae','acc'])
```

My aim is to predict probablity of a given word in a context.
I have list of sentences and I want to train this model:

```
   def train_lstm_model(self, sentences):

        sentences_as_indexes = []


        filtered_sentences = list(filter(lambda x : all([w in self.w2v_model.wv.vocab for w in x]) , sentences)) #filter to take only sentences with no OOV words
        for sentence in filtered_sentences:
            if all([w in self.w2v_model.wv.vocab for w in sentence]): #todo use filter
                indexes_row = []
                for word in sentence:

                    idx = self.w2v_model.wv.vocab.get(word).index
                    indexes_row.append(idx)

                sentences_as_indexes.append(indexes_row)
        X = pd.DataFrame([sentence[:-1] for sentence in sentences_as_indexes])
        y = pd.DataFrame([sentence[-1] for sentence in sentences_as_indexes])
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), ": Fitting LSTM model , size of X is ", X.shape)

        self.keras_lstm_model.fit(X, y) #HERE the error
```

Where sentences is list of around 1M sentences (my training set).
I Get the following error in the fit():

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[7,38] = -2147483648 is not in [0, 694415)
>        [[Node: embedding_1/embedding_lookup = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/Assign_2"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_1/embeddings/read, embedding_1/Cast, training/Adam/gradients/embedding_1/embedding_lookup_grad/concat/axis)]]

I though this might be because I have data that is OOV but as you can see - I filtered the sentences to take only those with all the word in the vocab.

What may cause this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Your example is too large but doesn't include code that would be necessary to run it (such as w2v). Your problem is likely due to different sentence lengths. You can use smaller examples and inspect the database.

Comment: @de1 added the w2v part , what do you mean problem with sentences lengths? How can I avoid it? the sentences are with different length since they are taken from natural corpus..